Precompile regular expressions to object file data segment?
In order to avoid dynamic allocation, I would like to precompile regular expressions into binary objects that I can link into a final executable. PCRE2 has explicit support for serializing compiled regexes, but it erases pointers and requires dynamically allocating new memory and copying the serialized data into it in order to get back to a state where the compiled regex can be executed.
I have tried compiling regular expressions and then writing out the struct literals as static variable declarations in a new C file (with pointers to the appropriate other static struct variables), which then itself gets compiled into an object file. I can then successfully link with that object file, and execute the compiled regexes with pcre2_match() without any errors,  pcre2_pattern_info gives all of the correct information about the patterns, and the match data shows the correct starting indices for matches, but somehow the regexes have been corrupted such that the match lengths are always zero (end index always matches start index).
So,

Is there a way to produce an object file with compiled regex data, which exposes symbols referring to the pcre2_code structs, which actually work, when passed into pcre2_match?

If not, is there any other regex library which would make this kind of pre-compilation possible?



Depending on how complete the regex support must be, you could use compile-time-regular-expressions (C++) and compile what you need into a library with a C API.

Look into re2c

You may want to check whether RE2 supports your use case.

Maybe it's possible to fix the bug in your approach. If you need advice on that, you may want to post a minimally reproducible example C source code (with tests) in a separate StackOverflow question.

Thanks to Shawn for suggesting looking into re2c; with that, I managed to solve my immediate problem.
I have ended up using this function to automatically create re2c-preprocessor files from individual regexes:
void compile_rgx(char *name, char *rgx) {
  char buf[512];
  snprintf(buf, 512, "%s.re", name);
  FILE *fp = fopen(buf, "w");
  fprintf(fp,
    "#include <stddef.h>\n"
    "#include <stdbool.h>\n"
    "/*!maxnmatch:re2c*/\n"
    "bool %s(const char *YYCURSOR, const char *YYLIMIT, char *yypmatch[YYMAXNMATCH * 2]) {\n"
    "  const char *YYMARKER; size_t yynmatch;\n"
    "  /*!stags:re2c format = 'const char *@@;'; */\n"
    "  for(;;)/*!re2c\n"
    "    re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;\n"
    "    re2c:eof = 0;\n"
    "    re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;\n"
    "    re2c:posix-captures = 1;\n"
    "    %*s { return true; }\n"
    "    $    { return false; }\n"
    "    *    { continue; }\n"
    "  */\n"
    "}", name, rgx);
  fclose(fp);
}

The makefile runs a compilation program that reads all the regular expressions from a config file, and uses that function to create the .re files; and then runs re2c on all of the generated files and pipes the output to gcc to create object files. (For my use case, I want all regexes to match at any position; if you want them to only match at the beginning of a string, remove the for(;;).) Using natively-compiled functions per regex ends up being faster than relying on a regex library, and reduces the final executable size by not linking in such a library. However, this is technically working around the original question rather than directly answering it, so there's still room for a proper answer here!
